# Treble: How do I check if it is enabled on my device?

Tags: adb, 8.0-oreo, termux, treble

Title says it all

By way of background [Project Treble](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/treble) was announced with release of Oreo to speed up OS updates by reducing OEM delay . Devices running Oreo out of the box are expected to have it , so how do I check if my device has it and I can expect faster updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For users not familiar with terminal and such, [Treble Check](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kevintresuelo.treble) saves some hassle, and on top of that also offers info on whether the device has A/B system partitions (for seamless updates).

Comment: Related https://android.stackexchange.com/q/223975/131553

Answer (score 8):

Works on unrooted devices also

Install [Termux](https://github.com/termux)
and run

`getprop ro.treble.enabled`

It returns `true` if your device supports and `false` if it doesn’t

With [adb](/questions/tagged/adb)

`adb shell getprop ro.treble.enabled`

Comment: Edited the answer to delete Termux link from Play store, which is outdated and added Github link